# Apache Camel Custom Component - Producer to invoke netty component

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have created Camel custom component and in which requirement is to invoke http producer endpoint to call webservice and return response.
Eg:

```
**Normal Route:**
  from(startRoute)
    log(inMessage)
    to(customComp:foo?parameters=value)
    log(outMessage);
```

**In Camel Custom Producer Endpoint:**

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  // get the exchange message 
     CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
     context.addRoutes(new MessageRoute());
     context.start();
  // post message using camel-http component - **facing challenge here** 
  // return message  
}
```

I do not what to invoke Create and start camelcontext on each route call (**from(startRoute)**) rather help in getting this requirement done in better way

Comment: I wouldn't invoke a camel component inside of a custom component but instead directly use a [HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html). [This page](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-guide) contains some good tutorials on how to setup and cofigure the HTTP client and invoke certain operations

Comment: I agree with Roman Vottner. Maybe another possibility to gain more flexibility is to use a ProducerTemplate in the CustomComponent to simply call other "standard" camel components. Add a parameter to your custom component with the endpointUri you need. In your case you can configure the netty component, but you can also change to any other component like file, jms, ....